# Send array via ajax to php

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I am sending array via ajax to PHP. How to get the array from PHP?

```
$('.send-image').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"sendimages.php",
        data: {
            images: imgArr
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
```

I tried with this, but its not working

```
$images = $_POST['imgArr'];
foreach($images as $d) {
    echo $d;
}
```

Comment: What is the output?  moreover what is the output of var_dump($_POST['imgArr']); ?  That should allow you to determine a solution.

Comment: Show us how you set `imgArr`

Comment: Thats my whole js - https://pastebin.com/zVt6zRxc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$images = $_POST['imgArr'];
```

With

```
$images = $_POST['images'];
```

Because the index `images` came from here:

```
data: {
    images: imgArr
}
```